# React Native - Styling buttons with styled-components

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I created a button with styled-components, but the styles are not applying. I tried with the stylesheet and it didn't work either.

How can I style this button?

Styled-Components area:

```
const CalcButton = styled.Button`
  margin-top:10px;
`;
```

My function:

```
 return (
    <Page>
      <HeaderText>Calculadora de Gorjeta</HeaderText>
      <Input
        placeholder="Quanto deu a conta?"
        keyboardType="numeric"
        value={bill}
        onChangeText={n=>setBill(n)}
      />
      <PctArea>
        <PctItem title="5%"  onPress={()=>setPct(5)}/>
        <PctItem title="10%" onPress={()=>setPct(10)}/>
        <PctItem title="15%" onPress={()=>setPct(15)}/>
        <PctItem title="20%" onPress={()=>setPct(20)}/>
      </PctArea>
      <CalcButton
        title={`Calcular ${pct}%`}
        onPress={calc}
      />
      {tip > 0 &&
        <ResultArea>
          <ResultItemTitle>Valor da Conta</ResultItemTitle>
          <ResultItem>R$ {parseFloat(bill).toFixed(2)}</ResultItem>

          <ResultItemTitle>Valor da Gorjeta</ResultItemTitle>
          <ResultItem>R$ {tip.toFixed(2)} ({pct}%)</ResultItem>

          <ResultItemTitle>Valor Total</ResultItemTitle>
          <ResultItem>R$ {(parseFloat(bill) + tip).toFixed(2)}</ResultItem>
        </ResultArea>
      }
    </Page>
```

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/button A basic button component that should render nicely on any platform. Supports a **minimal** level of customization. If this button doesn't look right for your app, you can build your own button using TouchableOpacity.

Comment: After switching to TouchableOpacity, it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all I recommend change the Button styled for TouchableOpacity.

The TouchableOpacity style is more like a div then a button, so u have to think about a div when u go style it.

The title attribute will be replaced for a Text component of React-Native itself

So the style code will be more like:

```
const CalcButton = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  `Your style`
`;
```

And the JSX code will be more like:

```
<CalcButton>
   <Text>What ever you want</Text>

</CalcButton>
```

Comment: I didn't know the buttons are not stylable, using the TouchableOpacity worked for me

Comment: they're more restricted to styled then a TouchableOpacity

Happy to help!!!

Comment: Now I understand that it is not very stylish, after switching to TouchableOpacity, it worked! Thanks